# Aborting request for updating data

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Say I have a user and they're trying to update their profile data. The request is sent but the internet is way too slow or got disconnected and the request keeps going forever.

In Retrofit and OkHttp, it's easy to cancel a request. But when it's a POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE, the request result is ignored, but the server still handles the request fully (updates data).

That means if the user cancels the update and the data is updated, the response of the successful update is ignored.

Is there a way to abort the request and terminate the backend code (PHP in my case) that's being executed to handle the request?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and it can happen in other ways too, for example, you submit something, the data gets processed by the server, and the result does not get back to the device (the packet gets lost on the way back).

In these cases, you need better UX design to handle these, for example, either not allow cancellation of the API, or if you do, call another API with cancellation and let the server know that the user has undone their decision and the data has to be restored.

Comment: Sending a cancellation request does sound logical. But sadly it has no guarantees either.

Comment: It doesn't, but the user can know that their cancellation is 'pending' via a loading, and if it fails, it can be retried (automatically or manually by user's command)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand your requirement of being able to cancel the request you've made because of slow connection and you haven't seen a response from server in a while.

> In your case it's profile update and end goal too. Even if you shoot
>   the request and haven't receive response you'll get the one on fresh
>   loading of profile or even after retrying to update you'll override
>   the already updated profile with new information.
>
> You don't need to increase extra burden of checking request
>   cancellation event sent by client on your server side code as tomorrow
>   it may need to serve large audience.
>
> Hope this clarifies because the secure solutions of doing DB roll
>   backs, some people go for shadow updates used by payment solutions 
>   aren't fit for this scenario.

**In case of sign up**: Even if you sent request it's been processed, on next attempt to send you get already registered error. So just go and login. Same goes for uploading content, you identify already existing or let user update them again doesn't harm anyways, he has right to update the data.

Same goes with other scenarios implementation, you have to check for already existence.

**In case of cancellation request:** People doesn't follow this as it comes with extra cost and needs double efforts.

Hope now this clarifies what you was looking for.

Comment: The user update is one example. Other examples are website pms, signing up, uploading content, etc